# How to make use of question alert button using sweetalert in laravel?

Tags: laravel, sweetalert2

I use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert, to create a confirmation alert, however i don't know how to set a statement to the alert button.

i'm using this line of code:

`Alert::question('Promoted To Admin?', 'Make this user as system admin?')`

and this is the output

[image]

Is there a way for me to add a statement to the button?, For example if okay button is click proceed with the next process and if cancel button is click on the sweetalert, cancel any process.

Answer (score 1):

```
As per my suggestion , you should be use that library. 

https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

It is completely modified library. We can do anything in this library.
```

Comment: looks like that's it. however, I would like to know if there's someone who know how to use the same command as me since it already provided.

Comment: We have to include he js library into the blade file use this as per needed. it is fully modified.